# Wrong break-word in Chrome?but right show in IE!! when using Chinese word in HTML code

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, line-breaks

My css:

```
   .testBox {
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: normal;
    }
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="testBox">
    <p>中新网北京1月4日电(记者 俞岚 周锐)中国对3.53亿元<span>人</span><span>民</span><span>币</span><span>。</span>这也是迄今为止中国开出的金额最高的一张价格违法罚单</p>
</div>
<div class="testBox">
    <p>中新网北京1月4日电(记者 俞岚 周锐)中国对3.53亿元人民币。这也是迄今为止中国开出的金额最高的一张价格违法罚单</p>
</div>
<div class="testBox">
    <p>123456789<span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span>d</span>efghigkilmnopqrstuvwxz</p>
</div>
<div class="testBox">
    <p>123456789abcdefghigkilmnopqrstuvwxz</p>
</div>
```

Please pay attention for “亿”！after that , there is a break-word in Chrome,but not in IE When

I've made some "span" wrapping the character.....why??? how to write to get the same effect

Answer (score 1):

In the [CSS documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-text-20030514/#wordbreak-props):

> The `word-break` property specifies line breaking rules for non-CJK scripts.
>
> **Tip:** CJK scripts are Chinese, Japanese and Korean ("CJK") scripts.

So, I guess it doesn't work for CJK Scripts...

Comment: A link to the CSS documentation would be helpful.

Comment: The link is outdated, to a version from 2003. The current CSS3 Text draft is dated 13 November, 2013, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/, and it does not contain a statement like the one quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
word-break: break-all;
```

According to the [CSS3 Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break) draft, such a setting allows a line break between any two letters. It adds: “This option is used mostly in a context where the text is predominantly using CJK characters with few non-CJK excerpts and it is desired that the text be better distributed on each line.”

The value `normal` means that “words break according to their usual rules”, which are more or less browser-dependent.